# How to get array elements in frequency in between two array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int []data = new int [SamData.length];
int count = 0;
for(int i=0;i<sampleInt;i++) {
    for(int f=0;f<UpLimit[0]; f++, UpLimit[0]++){
        if(20 <= UpLimit[i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
System.out.println(LowLimit[i] + "\t\t" + UpLimit[i] + "\t\t\t" + count);
}
}
```

1. what I need is if the user inputted values, for example...

   value1: 8
   value2: 16
   value3: 3
   value4: 13
   value5: 24

   it should check if the values are in between the upper and lower numbers.
   for example

   0-9 = 2          //(3,8)
   10-20 = 2        //(13,16)
   20-30 = 1        //(24)
   30-40 = 0
   and so on...

   but in the code it just show...
   0-9 = 1
   10-20 = 2
   20-30 = 3
   30-40 = 4
   and so on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.  First, create a class to handle your bounds objects:

```
public static class Bounds {
    private int lowerBounds;
    private int upperBounds;
    private int count = 0;
    
    public Bounds(int low, int high) {
        lowerBounds = low;
        upperBounds = high;
    }
    
    public int getLowerBounds() {
        return lowerBounds;
    }

    public int getUpperBounds() {
        return upperBounds;
    }

    public void checkValue(int value) {
        if (lowerBounds <= value && value < upperBounds) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return lowerBounds + "\t\t" + upperBounds + "\t\t\t" + count;
    }
}
```

Notice, this also handles string output.

Then initialize your bounds.  I'm not following exactly your bounds, but you can fix that to do what you need:

```
List<Bounds> boundsList= new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i+=10) {
    boundsList.add(new Bounds(i, i+9));
}
```

Then you can do your calculations

```
 for (int value : values) {
    for (Bounds bounds : boundsList) {
        bounds.checkValue(value);
    }
}
```

Then you can output:

```
for (Bounds bounds : boundsList) {
    System.out.println(bounds);
}
```